# How can I build a GUI to use inside a jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

The idea is to be able to build and use the GUI inside the notebook, so working with a long function that has a lot of parameters is more efficient than just typing the characters in the notebook.

Obviously not specifics, but if someone can point some library, project, links or any resources that might help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have looked all over internet. So far nothing. There's a message board in PyData where some developer states that [jupyter doesn't support GUI](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pynq_project/Z7_MSOcKmbg).

Aside from that, I was thinking perhaps working with [Bokeh](https://demo.bokehplots.com/apps/stocks) might work.

Another option perhaps to explore is using [these widgets](http://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20List.html).

See picture:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Consider using [ipywidgets](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

[image: https://bretahajek.com/2017/02/widgets-jupyter-ipwigdets/]

Image Source: https://bretahajek.com/2017/02/widgets-jupyter-ipwigdets/