# Pygame window won't show up in Jupyter

Tags: python, pygame, jupyter

I'm currently trying to program a tiny pygame game in a Jupyter notebook from a CoCalc project. As a first test, I just tried to display a window with this piece of code :

```
import pygame

background_colour = (255,255,255) 
(width, height) = (300, 200)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Tutorial 1')
screen.fill(background_colour)

pygame.display.flip()

running = True
while running:
  
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      running = False
      pygame.quit()
```

The problem is that **the window doesn't even show up in the jupyter notebook**. I litteraly *copy pasted* the code from the internet to make sure there wasn't any error, so I'm suspecting the problem comes from Jupyter itself (the video driver for example). **Is there a workaround for this, or is this simply impossible to use pygame with Jupyter?**

Comment: Do you get any error or warnings?

Answer (score 0):

It seems just as Jupyter Notebook doesn't support GUIs, so I think they won't support pygame either…

Take a look at [How can I build a GUI to use inside a jupyter notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42686763/how-can-i-build-a-gui-to-use-inside-a-jupyter-notebook)